# How to add separate images into step bar on flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to add steps images to each step in the "anotherstepper" bar how to do that?

ex: at the step 1 circle I want add step 1 image , at the 2nd step 2 circle I want add step 2 image like that I mean.I hope you ca understand what I mean.

code

```
Container(
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        child: AnotherStepper(
          stepperList: stepperData,
          stepperDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          horizontalStepperHeight: 100,
          dotWidget: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(children: const <Widget>[
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/step1.png'),
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ]),
                Row(children: const <Widget>[
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/step2.png'),
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ]),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          activeBarColor: Colors.green,
          inActiveBarColor: Colors.grey,
          activeIndex: 2,
          barThickness: 8.5,
          gap: 30,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
late double activeIndex;
  List<StepperData> stepperData = [
    StepperData(
      title: "",
      subtitle: "",
    ),
    StepperData(
      title: "",
      subtitle: "",
    ),
    StepperData(
      title: "",
      subtitle: "",
    ),
    StepperData(
      title: "",
      subtitle: "",
    ),
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
```

I want Like this

[image]

But my Output

[image]

Comment: what library that you use?

Comment: @fairycatto "another stepperbar" library

Comment: I suggest the same thing that mentioned by Aviraj Patel, that package doesn't support to adding several image into stepper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using https://pub.dev/packages/another_stepper

this `another_stepper` package but it doesn't support different images, it supports only one image.
please use another stepper package.

i suggest to go with this:
https://pub.dev/packages/im_stepper
`im_stepper`

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use Stack Widget instead of using column.

Remove the column and add stack like this:

```
Stack(
         children: <Widget>[
            Row(children: const <Widget>[
              Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/step1.png'),
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ]),
                Row(children: const <Widget>[
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/step2.png'),
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ]),
```